# PHP: Close socket via ssh that was opened with php

Tags: php, linux, sockets, ssh

What are the commands to close sockets that were opened by php?  I accessed the script via http and now I can't bind back to the port because the socket is still open....?

How can I close these sockets from the ssh terminal?

It is a linux server.

I saw that you can use netstat to view open connections and shutdown(3SOCKET) or something to close, but I'm not sure if that 3 is the resource id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this is to completely kill the process that owns the socket.

```
sudo netstat -ap | grep :<port_number>
kill  <pid>
```

Comment: But what if the socket is no longer owned by any process? In my case, it's a PHP script that creates a socket. Closing the socket in PHP with `fclose($socket)` doesn't work and the socket stays open for a whole minute after any activity is finished, no matter what I do.